# How to save and reload standing queries of StreamInsight

Tags: c#, .net, streaminsight

I have a StreamInsight server, It streams data by standing query. When the StreamInsight is running, I restart that server, after the server is restarted, I want the StreamInsight continues to run with old standing query.

Can I do that ?
If I can, how do I do that ?

Comment: I found the way that StreamInsight can resume after restarting server, we can use StreamInsight Resiliency. Please follow this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290501(v=sql.111).aspx